# JAX-RS @PathParam: how to pass anything including "?"

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I have the following JAX-RS method with @PathParam.

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Path("collect/{orderItemID}")
public Response collect(@PathParam("orderItemID") String orderItemID) {
    System.out.println("Order Item ID: " + orderItemID);
    ....
}
```

I want the method to accept anything that is passed to it. However, when I pass the following string, the container, WebLogic, returned HTTP 404 Not Found. The problem is with the ? in the beginning of the string. If I remove the ?, it will get accepted and the System.out.println() method will print out the value.

```
?ProductCode=yyy&EntityNo=1234&Name=what&FileReference=xxx
```

Next I changed the @Path to the following value:

```
@Path("collect/{orderItemID : (.+)?}")
```

This time, when I passed the above string with the ?, there is no more HTTP 404 Not Found. However, inside the method, System.out.println() now prints a blank value of orderItemID.

How do I specify @Path so that the method can accept *anything*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying use in the URL

```
?ProductCode=yyy&EntityNo=1234&Name=what&FileReference=xxx
```

is called a [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). This is not something that you try to as a single path parameter. When the URL is retrieved by Jersey, it will parse the URL and extract the query string. It knows it's a query string because of the `?`.

Once it has query string, it will parse it, splitting the `=` and `&`, and make the key value pairs available in a number of different ways. One way to get them inside of the resource method is just to use `@QueryParam`. With this annotation, you can use the key, and the *value* of that key will get passed to the method

```
public Response collect(@QueryParam("ProductCode") String productCode,
                        @QueryParam("EntityNo") String entityNo,
                        @QueryParam("Name") String name,
                        @QueryParam("FileReference") String fileRef) {}
```

If you goal is to actually be able to pass *anything* and you problem is actually about passing a `?` (that is not a reference to the query string), when what you need to do is something like

```
@Path("{anything: .*}")
```

Then on the client side, you need to [URL encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#URL_encoding) the `?`

Comment: Hi, I do know about the @QueryParam and I know that I can use it for the query string. But that is not what my question is about. I want the client to be able to pass anything, including a string that happens to look like a query string. Your solution has the same effect as my original solution. If the client doesn't encode the ?, the container will not return HTTP 404, but inside the method the string will be empty. The client should not know that it needs to encode the ?. So are you saying that there is no way to pass ? as first character without encoding it?

Comment: Yes, the client _should_ and _must_ know what they need to encode. There are a list of special characters that the client must know that needs to be encoded. This is just how URLs works. This in nothing specific to Jersey. This is the same for the `=` and the `&`. These are special characters that _must_ be encoded, if they are not to be used in its intended purpose (of the query string)

Comment: OK peeskillet, I get what you mean. Thanks for your replies. I will accept your answer.